# SCSS: node-sass replacement for old Compass image-width function

Tags: css, npm, sass, compass, node-sass

I am porting an legacy web project that used Compass for SCSS compilation to build with node-sass since Compass requires Ruby and seems to be about three years dead.

One of the SCSS files contains calls to the 'image-width' function supported by Compass:

```
padding-left: $message-box-icon-padding * 2 + image-width('messages/loading.gif');
width: image-width('messages/loading.gif');
height: image-width('messages/loading.gif');
```

Fortunately there are only three and it seems the third should have been `image-height`.

What should replace these calls to image-width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sprite-magic-importer replaces most of the features of COMPASS.